# Run executeBatch() efficiently

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

We are having a batch application in which each record is written into the db using a stored procedure which has just an `INSERT` statement inside it.

```
Stored Procedure ( params ):
    INSERT INTO table VALUES params
```

But when those stored procedures are added to the batch for each record, the `executebatch()` performance it not as expected as it would be when individual `INSERT`s are given.

We don't want to pass an array as bulk to the stored procedure. We also dont want to write an `INSERT` statement in the code. How do we overcome this problem with `executeBatch()` performance ?

Comment: can you show us your code please?

Comment: You can try to explore performance with Oracle anonymous block like `BEGIN EXECUTE your_stored_proc(...);EXECUTE your_stored_proc(...); END;` and then call it once as regular Query not through JDBC executebatch... It may save some time, but may not. I used that technique long time ago and I do not remember all details around. Of course it will be one transaction for all inserts.

Comment: @Vadim I have tried that, but it is not as efficient as the `executeBatch()`